# TLS issue when upgrading my app from Heroku-18 to Heroku-20

Tags: ruby, ssl, heroku, openssl

I tried to upgrade my app from Heroku-18 to Heroku-20 and get the error **"SSL_connect returned = 1 errno = 0 state = error dh key too small"** apparently related to Ubuntu 20.04 Openssl security level 2 and TLS version 1.2 with whom you work

I've contacted the e-invoice authorization website that returns the error, but they don't have a fixed date to upgrade to TLS 1.2

I need to know what else I have to solve the DEFAULT@SECLEVEL problem because soon I will be forced to switch to Heroku-20 and my application will not be able to work.

If there is a way to temporarily change the Openssl security value in HEROKU to 1 . DEFAULT@SECLEVEL to 1 or something equivalent.

Comment: Hey there, any chance you have found a solution for this in the meantime?

Comment: Hi, the only solution I found was to develop an own api on AWS that interfaces with my system on heroku

Answer (score 0):

I fixed using this build pack: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/riskmethods/heroku-buildpack-openssl-seclevel